# Couldn't build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, firebase

Can someone help me out with this?

When I compile the application I get an error equal to this: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

Please take a look https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsUOB.jpg

I tried to use this method and it did not work
1. Quit Xcode.
2. Delete project's temp files located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
3. Delete ProjectName.xcworkspace
4. Delete Podfile.lock file and Pods folder
5. Run pod install.
6. Open the newly created ProjectName.xcworkspace file and build.

Comment: Generally, linked screen shots should not be in questions as if the link breaks, it invalidates the question. Much better to include the actual image. Looking at the link though, it appears those are two different projects? It's kind of hard to tell from the link.

Comment: @Jay this the projects are linked together, one as Project.xcodeproj & the other as Project.xworkspace

Comment: Understood. Ensure you are only directly opening the .xcworkspace file from the Finder and not the .xcodeproj file. It still looks like you have two different projects open or they are somehow disconnected because it doesn't appear like the actual project had the pods installed correctly. There would normally be a *Pods* project icon at the same level as the *LoginScreen* project but I dont see it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appeared after upgrading to Xcode 12.

Apparently removing the build configuration for valid architectures (VALID_ARCHS) fixes the problem. [See Xcode 12 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-release-notes).

To fix, just set:

> Build Settings / TARGET / Architectures / Build Active Architecture
> Only / Yes

I hope to help other people not to waste time with this